# Compass - how generate two or more sprites layout from one folder

Tags: sass, compass-sass

I am a newbie in Sass / Compass. I tried to generate sprites, it works without any problems.

I cant find how to generate two sprite layouts from one folder with images. I dont want to create 2 folders with the same content (duplicate images only because of 2 or more different sprites layouts).

It is possible to do this?

my code generate one group of sprites (diagonal) and now i want to generate horizontal and vertical ..

```
$vlajky-spacing: 20px;
$vlajky-layout: diagonal;
@import "vlajky/*.png";
@include all-vlajky-sprites;
```

Comment: Why do you need this?

Comment: Because sometimes in project i need use vertical and horizontal layout together.

Comment: Why? Compass deals with sprites layout for you, you don't have to care about it.

Comment: Sorry, dont understand my question ...

Answer (score 0):

I've had this problem, best thing is to generate two sprite maps, all you need to do is put them in separate folders depending on which you want them to appear in. This way you can have separate rules for spacing /positioning too.

```
@import "vlajky-horizontal/*.png";
@import "vlajky-vertical/*.png";

@include all-vlajky-horizontal-sprites;
@include all-vlajky-vertical-sprites;
```